# How to rotate a 3 dimensional matrix by 90 degrees clockwise around its central element?

Tags: c, algorithm, multidimensional-array, rotation

Can you suggest me an algorithm to rotate a three dimensional array of size 3x3x3 around its central element (say matrix[1][1][1]), accordind to x, y, and z axes of the 3D coordinate system?

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach is pretty simple, I think: figure out how to do it for a 2-D matrix and apply it in each of the planes of the 3-D matrix that is perpendicular to the axis of rotation. The details of all this depend on the order in which elements of the matrix are stored, which you haven't specified.

Answer (score 0):

I think, we can not do that for 2D. How can we get central element in 2D or in any even dimensional matrix??

We can apply this technique only on odd size matrices. For even size, just perform the basics.